# Warning : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in theme php on line 56

Tags: themes

I found this error but not sure what should I do, I already disabled the plugins and activated them again but same error shows in the reviews page of each product.

Gladly appreciate your help

Here's the exact error:

> Warning
> : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> /home/blossomt/public_html/wp-content/themes/rubens/template/single-product/_review.php

> on line 56

So I went to my theme editor and here's what I see on line 56, but not sure if I should touch this code, I'm not a coder:

```
printf('<div class="rate"><div class="starscont">%s </div></div>',
```

Comment: So this is the comment about this  error inside the theme editor: printf('<div class="rate"><div class="starscont">%s </div></div>',

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is a warning, not an error. The code that you posted does not look like foreach at all, if you can paste the code that has a foreach close to that line, we might be able to help.

If you did not write the theme, don't try and fix it unless you know what you are trying to do.

Write the following in your **wp-config.php** file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

(change WP_DEBUG to false if you are in production)

That warning won't show up any longer. Look inside wp-content for a file called debug.log and examine the errors there. If functionality is not affected, I would simply ignore this before changing the code of something you are not familiar with.